# Strange behaviour of php file_get_contents

Tags: javascript, php

I am facing some strange behaviour of executing a php script and I cannot figure out what's causing this.

I have this php script in file called grabber.php

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['url'];
//$url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=usd+to+egp/';
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

When calling this script directly (commenting first line and uncomment second line), I get the required result, however when calling this script from Java script passing $url in below code I get a empty results:

```js
const usdPriceURI = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=usd+to+egp/'
$('#responseUsd').load('/php/grabber.php?url=' + usdPriceURI);
```

Note:
$('#responseUsd') is a div with id responseUsd

Comment: Sounds like you did not even do the most basic debugging here so far - not even checking what `$_GET['url']` within your PHP script _actually_ contains?

Comment: Make sure you URL-encode any parameter values before you pass into them to the .load() command...

Comment: Because you neglected to apply proper URL encoding to the value that you are _Introducing into_ a second URL there, the value of that parameter within your PHP script will now be `https://www.google.com/search?q=usd to egp/` - the `+` have been decoded back into space characters. And other than a common browser, when you type a URL into the address bar, `file_get_contents` will _not_ automatically apply URL encoding, to make those spaces _into_ `+` characters again, as Google expects them.

Comment: FYI: Trying to scrape Google's frontend result pages, will likely not work for very long. Google will probably recognize this as "bot traffic" after a while, and will then require solving of a CAPTCHA first.

Comment: If you add a URL to the query of another url, There are a lot of special characters in the url that are not allowed in the query string without first encoding it.  I prefer base64 because it looks cleaner, but if I remember right you have to remove the trailing '=' signs.  I use this many times for "redirect after login" stuff.   You can use `btoa()`  in JS, and in php `base64_decode()`

Comment: On a side note, you've built an app that allows anyone to share a link to your site that returns anything they want from your own domain (for example, a carefully crafted HTML document with JavaScript). This opens up the possibility to trick your users and steal their credentials or information.

Comment: Absolutely. And on top of the risk of someone passing in the URL of a malicious page, you're also seemingly assuming someone will definitely pass in the URL of another website, but actually file_get_contents will work just as well to fetch the contents of your server's hard drive too...so you're basically giving away the contents of your disk for anyone interested. This is a security nightmare and a terrible idea, without employing a really solid whitelisting effort to protect your server and your users. I assume perhaps it started as a naive attempt to circumvent CORS restrictions??

Comment: Using urlencoding did not help, I solved my problem changing '....usd+to+egp' to '....usdtoegp'. Thank you all for valuable comments.

Comment: What you have done is one aspect of what url encoding would do anyway. We don't know how you applied the encoding because you didn't show it, but I would assume if it didn't work then actually you simply applied it incorrectly. You should use full encoding functions because in future a different url might have other characters needing encoding, not just the ones in this specific example. Show us your updated code if you need help with applying the encoding properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL-encode any parameter you pass into a URL, in case it contains characters which are considered meaningful in a URL, otherwise it can mess up the syntax of the main URL.

In this specific case, since you are attempting to pass another URL in as the parameter value, that is especially necessary since it's pretty much guaranteed to contain such characters.

```
const usdPriceURI = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=usd+to+egp/'
$('#responseUsd').load('/php/grabber.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(usdPriceURI));
```

should solve your problem.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent